# notification mailbox like SO in dot net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

[image]

I need idea and reference on developing notification mailbox as above picture.

```
<li><a href="Default.aspx"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-envelop"></span><span class="txt" style="color:red"> My Task</span></a>(<strong><span class="notification" id="txtContactCount" style="color:darkred" runat="server">0</span></strong>)</li>
```

Comment: Are you using a design framework like Bootstrap? If so, try this: http://www.bootply.com/tB4UXeU5pi

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax and appy below jquery and CSS to create notification mailbox same as your image example. http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/create-a-facebook-like-notifications-using-jquery-css.htm

See demo link http://www.encodedna.com/jquery/demo/showing-facebook-style-notifications-popup-window.htm#

I hope this will help you.